# dpkg with no shell

Tags: scripts, dpkg, udev

How to run dpkg without shell?

Here is my problem:

I made and autorun.sh script in my USB key.

To run this script, I created rules in `/etc/udev/rules/49-usb-rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*1", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh /opt/local/usb_autorun.sh %E{ID_FS_LABEL} %E{ID_FS_UUID}"
```

`/opt/local/usb_autorun.sh` calls my `autorun.sh` located on my USB key.

It works well, but in that script, I try to run `dpkg -i` to install a Debian archive and it fails.

After some research, I tried to run:

```
at -f /media/usb-key/autorun.sh -v 12:00
```

And i had the same problem.

So I saw that `dpkg` seems to need a shell to be run.

I tried `dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=dialog debconf`` and set up non-interactive, but it didn't seems to work neither.

How can I run `dpkg -i` from my `autorun.sh` script?

Here is my autorun.sh (on the usb key):

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/fic

echo "Installation du firmware" > /tmp/fic

DIR=$( readlink -f "$( dirname "$0" )")

export PATH=$PATH

/usr/bin/dpkg -i --force-all $DIR/radiolive.deb >> /tmp/fic 2>&1

echo "FIN" >> /tmp/fic
```

Here is my usb_autorun.sh (on my hard-drive):

```
 #!/bin/bash

 SCRIPT=autorun.sh

 autorun() {
 if [ -z ${1} ]; then
    FILE=/media/${2}/${SCRIPT}
 else
    FILE=/media/${1}/${SCRIPT}
 fi

 sleep 10

  if [ -f ${FILE} ]; then
    /bin/bash ${FILE}
  fi
 }

 autorun $@ &
```

Comment: (1) As far as I know, you need administrator privileges to run dpkg -i and install a package. You should use `gksu`. (2) Have you made the file executable (chmod +x)? (3) Have you added the #!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash on top of the file? (4) It would help if you post the contents of the script.

Comment: @medigeek `gksu` is graphical, and will fail if run in the background like this. Since `dpkg` is a non-graphical program, it can simply be run with `sudo`. (But if the script is itself running as `root`, then of course neither is necessary.)

Comment: udev is run as root. In my autorun.sh i create the file: "-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 317  5 juil. 14:02 /tmp/fic". So this script is well executed and with the good privileges. But thank's for your answer. My script has the shebang #!/bin/sh

Comment: ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} is not supported in sh, but then again you run the file autorun.sh with /bin/bash in the usb_autorun script so that should work in theory... Try using #!/bin/bash shebang on both autorun and usb_autorun -- is there any output in /tmp/fic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

BASH_SOURCE is a "bad substitution" for sh.

On the other hand, I found this:

http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#external-run

> udev does not run these programs on any active terminal, and it does
>   not execute them under the context of a shell. Be sure to ensure your
>   program is marked executable, **if it is a shell script ensure it starts
>   with an appropriate shebang** (e.g. #!/bin/sh), and do not expect any
>   standard output to appear on your terminal.

So basically the problems could be:

a) You're not using a shebang for the usb_autorun.sh and you need to add `#!/bin/bash` to both autorun.sh and usb_autorun.sh

b) try this line instead and use #!/bin/sh on both autorun.sh and usb_autorun.sh:

```
DIR=$( readlink -f "$( dirname "$0" )")
```

Note: This solution is a bit unsafe (Anyone can run anything in autorun.sh and get it executed), but on a local basis I believe it's harmless. Nevertheless, I would use some other name instead of "autorun.sh", such as "install_deb.sh" -- just to avoid any malware scripts.

Comment: Thank's a lot! You were right! All is working well now! For the malware you are right, i will rename my autorun.sh. Thank's medigeek! I also had to add "export PATH" before dpkg instruction for this to work but now it's ok!

Comment: I also had to edit my rules and give him a numer greater than 49 to be sure to be execute.